# Firestore Realtime Database metrics not matching database operation?

Tags: java, android, google-cloud-firestore

I'm comparing the read and write metrics from my new Firestore account with a first time launch of some database code, but they don't match.

Here's the code which I've only run once in Android:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private FirebaseFirestore db;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        db = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();

        Map<String, Object> user = new HashMap<>();

        for(int i = 0; i < 1000; i++) {
            user.put("value", String.valueOf(i));
            db.collection("files").document(String.valueOf(i)).set(user);
        }
    }
}
```

and here's the metrics:

[image]

Why did I get over 5000 reads and only 414 writes?

Comment: Do you have the Firebase Console open?

Comment: Yes, but I've already made other database transactions.  LOL I'm actually reading your website page about reducing Firestore reads :)

Comment: So that's the expected behavior, right? Since you already made other database transactions.

Comment: Sorry, I meant after I posted this. All of the metrics from the image is just launching the app once, so I was expecting only 1000 writes and 0 reads, but it seems like there's more going on in the background?

Comment: If you have the Console open, most likely this is the reason why you see that.

Comment: Really? 5.4K reads? And why only 414 writes when I added 1000 objects?

Comment: If your app is heavily used, leaving the Console open, is not such a good idea.

Comment: Oh, I see what your getting at.... the console is observing every single change that is occurring in real time which is acting as another device connected to the database?

Comment: Yes, that's right.

Comment: @jamesfields Could you also post your conclusion as the answer? This will help other community members with the same question.

Answer (score 1):

The console is observing every single change that is occurring in real time which is acting as another device connected to the database.

If you have the Console open, most likely this is the reason why you see a large number of reads. When your app is heavily used, leaving the Console open, is not such a good idea.